# Sales force EMP connector, stops receiving notification after some time

Tags: streaming-api

I am performing a POC to check Streaming API stability, POC is as follows

Program 1 : subscribe to pushtopic created against Account object Program 2 : create, update & delete single record after every 10 min interval

Both this programs were kept running for more than 12 hours (left overnight), after that I verified if all notification are received or not and found that after sometime (in this case it was nearly ~ 2 hours 45 min ) no notification were received, I repeated this twice and both case it stops getting notification after sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in to a similar issue using the emp-connector application. For me, it turned out to be two different issues. The first issue was that my Salesforce session was expiring for the user logged in from emp-connector. The second issue was that emp-connector does not resubscribe when the Bayeux client reconnects after an unsuccessful message is received from the server. The message that usually caused that is `403: Unknown client`. It took me a while to understand what was going on, in the process I ended up writing my own connector. My connector will periodically login in to extend the session, as well as resubscribe when the client reconnects. You can find the code here: https://github.com/cdowney/sf-messaging-client

Comment: Right coryd , even I end up doing same the only difference is that I subscribe to meta channel and login & re-subscribe in case of error instead of doing periodically